# Wing IDE not stopping at break point for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, breakpoints

I'm new to Python, Wing IDE and Google cloud apps.

I've been trying to get Wing IDE to stop at a breakpoint on the local (Windows 7) Google App Engine. I'm using the canned guestbook demo app and it launches fine and responds as expected in the web browser.

However breakpoints are not working. I'm not sure if this is important but I see the following status message when first starting the debugger:
Debugger: Debug process running; pid=xxxx; Not listening (too many connections) ...

My run arguments are as per the recommendation in the Wing IDE help file section "Using Wing IDE with Google App Engine", namely:
`C:\x\guestbook --max_module_instances=1 --threadsafe_override=false`

One problem I found when trying to follow these instructions. The instructions say go into Project Properties and the Debug/Execute tab and set the Debug Child Processes to Always Debug Child Process. I found this option doesn't exist.

Note also that in the guestbook app, if I press the pause button, the code breaks, usually in the python threading.py file in the wait method (which makes sense).

Further note also that if I create a generic console app in Wing IDE, breakpoints work fine.

I'm running 5.1.9-1 of Wing IDE Personal.
I've included the Google appengine directory and the guestbook directories in the python path.

Perhaps unrelated but I also find that sys.stdout.write strings are not appearing in the Debug I/O window.

Comment: Here is how I fixed it via answers posted -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961484/wing-ide-not-stopping-at-break-points?noredirect=1#comment73017963_42961484

Answer (score 5):

I have copied the wingdbstub.py file (from debugger packages of Wing ide) to the folder I am currently running my project on and used 'import wingdbstub' & initiated the debug process. All went well, I can now debug modules.

Answer (score 2):

As often happens with these things, writing this question gave me a couple of ideas to try. I was using the Personal edition ... so I downloaded the professional edition ... and it all worked fine.

Looks like I'm paying $95 instead of $45 when the 30 day trial runs out.