# Wing IDE not stopping at break points

Tags: python, debugging, wing-ide

I am running a project that makes calls to C++ framework functions and python modules, I can run it on Wing IDE with no problems (personal version). However, I can not debug on the run. It only lets me debug a certain file, which is pretty useless. I make a call to a shell script to run the framework function via a python file (init) and that function calls a python module that I want to debug. I have had the same problem with pyCharm. I have spent quite a while trying to figure this out, something that should be very basic. How can I fix this problem and debug on the go???

Comment: Do you run your program via a .py file that that imports the C++ framework or are you launching a C++ program that then executes your python code?  If it's the latter, you probably need to use Wing's support for debugging externally launched code as described in https://wingware.com/doc/debug/debugging-externally-launched-code

Comment: I use a pyton file to call shell scripts from within python as below:
    
  `[import os
    import subprocess
    import pdb
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK'] = '1'
    env['PYTHONPATH'] = '.'
    env['GLOG_logtostderr'] = '1'
    subprocess.call(["/home/duygu/Desktop/lisa-caffe-public-   lstm_video_deploy/build/tools/caffe","train", "-solver",   "lstm_solver.prototxt", "-weights", "pretrained.caffemodel"], env=env)`

and that calls a python module at some point.
 
 I will check the link, thank you.

Comment: You're launching a non-Python process so if you're starting debug with the above Wing can't debug-instrument the child process because it's not Python and then when it calls Python we have no way of debugging that.  The way to work with this kind of a setup is to use 'import wingdbstub' to import a copy of the wingdbstub.py that is in your Wing installation to initiate debug.  See http://wingware.com/doc/debug/debugging-externally-launched-code for details on how to set that up.

Comment: @Wingware Thanks a lot for your answer, I am skimming through the link and it is an alien concept for me. Do you know where I can find wingdbdstub.py?? When I try to download source code it asks me my customer name etc. (I am only using pro trial version right now / switched from personal one to see if this version has the feature I was asking about)

Comment: Nevermind! I found it under debugger packages

Comment: Got it working with wingdbdstub.py ! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @dusa you should write an answer with the complete solution (and mark it as accepted) to not leave the question hanging unanswered

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks, however seems like stack flow doesn't accept my answers anymore. To anyone who is having the same issue, to sum up:

Following the comments above, I have copied the  wingdbstub.py file (from debugger packages of Wing ide) to the folder I am currently running my project on and used 'import wingdbstub' & initiated the debug process. All went well.

Comment: It can wait until you get more reputation, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above, I have copied the wingdbstub.py file (from debugger packages of Wing ide) to the folder I am currently running my project on and used 'import wingdbstub' & initiated the debug process. All went well, I can now debug modules.